# MongoDB Node findone how to handle no results?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Im using the npm `mongodb` driver with node.

I have

```
collection.findOne({query}, function(err, result) {
    //do something
}
```

The problem is say I dont have any results, `err` is still `null` whether I find a result or don't. How would I know that there were no results found with the query?

I've also tried

```
info = collection.findOne(....
```

But the `info` is just `undefined` (it looked asynchronous so I didn't think it was the way to go anyway..)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Not finding any records isn't an error condition, so what you want to look for is the lack of a value in `result`.  Since any matching documents will always be "truthy", you can simply use a simple `if (result)` check. E.g.,

```
collection.findOne({query}, function(err, result) {
    if (err) { /* handle err */ }

    if (result) {
        // we have a result
    } else {
        // we don't
    }
}
```

Comment: findOne is deprecated

Comment: @Stepan. What is the best way to query for single doc then

Comment: @Shashank, check my answer

Comment: @StepanYakovenko, Thanks. Actually commented before seeing ur answer. I used it by the way. Thanks again.

Comment: @Shashank I am always willing to help

Comment: Note (for anyone coming across this answer) findOne() is no longer deprecated

Comment: Does the same happen with `updateOne()`? Will both `error` and `result` be "falsy" if the document could not be updated because it doesn't exist?

Answer (score 9):

All of these answers below are outdated. findOne is [deprecated](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/2.0/lib/collection.js). Lastest 2.1 documentation proposes to use

```
find(query).limit(1).next(function(err, doc){
   // handle data
})
```

Comment: Good to know. But what if there is no result? Does it return an error or an undefined `doc`?

Comment: you can also add another callback when iteration is done as far as i understand.

Comment: `find().limit()` returns a Cursor whose hasNext() can be used to determine whether it has any matching documents.

Comment: ChrisV mentioned this on my answer earlier, but for anyone coming across this, please note that [`findOne()`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/queries.html#find-first-occurence-with-findone) is no longer deprecated.

Comment: @LukaszWiktor - i'd like to know as well - i can't find any docs specifically confirming this, but I think if there are no results it returns `null`.

Answer (score 5):

Simply as:

```
collection.findOne({query}, function(err, result) {
    if (!result) {
        // Resolve your query here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

nowadays - since [node 8](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v8.0.0/#say-hello-to-async_hooks) - you can do this inside an `async` function:

```
async function func() {
  try {
    const result = await db.collection('xxx').findOne({query});
    if (!result) {
      // no result
    } else {
      // do something with result
    }
  } catch (err) {
    // error occured
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If result is null then mongo didn't find a document matching your query. Have tried the query from the mongo shell?

Answer (score -9):

```
collection.findOne({query}, function(err, result) {
   if (err) { /* handle err */ }

   if (result.length === 0) {
    // we don't have result
   }
}
```

Comment: `result` isn't an array, so this would simply throw an error (e.g., "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined") in the case where the query didn't match any records.  In the case where the query did match a record, then `length` still won't refer to what that code is expecting it to.