# Meteor-Mongo: Error handling for findone

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am trying to handle errors using `findOne` in meteor-mongo.

From [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10551313/mongodb-node-findone-how-to-handle-no-results), it appears that I should be able to handle errors by doing `collection.findOne({query}, function(err, result){ <handleError> }`, but doing so results in an errormessage:

> "Match error: Failed Match.OneOf, Match.Maybe or Match.Optional validation"

The following code works:

```
export default createContainer((props) => {
  let theID = props.params.theID;
  Meteor.subscribe('thePubSub');
  return {
    x: theData.findOne({_id: theID}),
  };
}, App);
```

The following code does not:

```
export default createContainer((props) => {
  let theID = props.params.theID;
  Meteor.subscribe('thePubSub');
  return {
    x: theData.findOne({_id: theID}, function(err,result){
      if(!result){
        return {}
      };
    }),
  };
}, App);
```

What am I doing wrong and how should I be resolving this error? Is this a meteor specific error?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: that match error looks like something generated by the match package on the server. you're seeing that error in the browser console or server console?

Comment: Hi @zim, thank you for the reply. This error is generated on the browser console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of error are you exactly trying to handle with your callback?

[Meteor's `findOne`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-findOne) is different from node's `mongodb` driver's `findOne` that the post you link to uses.

The expected signature is:

> collection.findOne([selector], [options])

There is no callback involved, since the method runs synchronously (but is reactive).

If you want to return a default value when the document is not found, you can simply use a JS logical OR:

```js
// Provide an alternative value on the right that will be used
// if the left one is falsy.
theData.findOne({_id: theID}) || {};
```

A more rigorous approach would be to compare its type with

```js
typeof queryResult === 'undefined'
```

Note that if `theData` collection is fed by the above subscription `Meteor.subscribe('thePubSub')`, I doubt Meteor will have time to populate the collection on the client by the time you query it…

Comment: I'm trying to handle errors if the id cannot be found. How should I be doing this if I want to differentiate between if the document is `undefined` or if the document hasnt been queried for?

Comment: What do you mean by "hasnt been queried for"?

Comment: Meaning, if I load the component and start the `createContainer` function, my document `x` is not ready yet, but will soon be if the id being queried for is valid. However if the id being queried for is not valid, then `x` will become undefined. How can the system know if the document is undefined because of the initial lag time or if its after a failed query?

Comment: Then you are probably looking for the `onReady` callback of [`Meteor.subscribe`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html#Meteor-subscribe) that will be executed once the client [receives a full snapshot](http://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html#Subscription-ready) of your server publication.

Comment: just saw the edited response. Logical OR does the trick. Thank you so much!